# Autofill text fields depending on dropbox value in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to make some of my text fields to auto fill with zero(0),
when the user selects NA in one dropdown.. How can I achieve that? Is there
any rails way to do that??

I have seen lot of jquery to accomplish auto fill values.. But I am new to
rails as well as am **zero** at jquery.. That is why I am looking for a
rails way to do that.

Kindly please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to learn some basic jquery as this can be accomplished in a simple manner using it. Basically, you have to attach a handler to the `change` event of the select box and based on it's value (NA), assign the zero value to the text field.

Look at this example:

```
# some_view.html.erb
<%= text_field_tag 'name', params[:name], id: 'name_text_field' %>
<%= select_tag 'category', options_for_select(..., params[:category]), id: 'category_select' %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#category_select').change(function(){
    var select = $(this);
    if (select.val() == "NA") {
      $('#name_text_field').val("0");
    }
  });
</script>
```

The view shows two inputs - one text field and one select box. Using jquery a handler (an inline function) is attached to the `change` event of this select box. Inside the handler the select can be referenced as `$(this)`, its value is tested for the "NA" string and if it matches, the value of the text field is set. That's all!

Have a look at the jquery documentation for the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event, the [`val()` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for getting/setting an input's value. And be sure to read some [intro](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bay3D/0/1?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1) on [jquery](http://andreehansson.se/the-basics-of-jquery/) as well...

Comment: Thanks a bunch @BoraMa

Answer (score -1):

There's a gem available, [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete), which you might want to take a look at. I haven't used it myself, but it seems good enough.

Comment: If I understand the OP question correctly, he does not need autocomplete (i.e. completion upon typing letters in a drop down combo box). All he needs is to set a text field value based on selecting another's select box value.